# How to fix broken packages after AMDGPU-PRO install fail

Tags: apt, package-management, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

I had amdgpu-pro 17.40 installed and running fine but had some issues with a specific display (Dell U3014) not working over displayport. I opened a ticket with AMD and they suggested an update to amdgpu-pro 17.50.

Running the installer for amdgpu-pro 17.50 failed and has broken package manager such that I can not install or uninstall anything. I have reached out to AMD for help but have not gotten any response in 5 days...simply that they are still looking into it.

The results of install script and attempts to fix are:

```
 ./amdgpu-pro-install 
[sudo] password for xxxx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core (= 17.50-511655) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: amdgpu-dkms (= 17.50-511655) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu (= 1:2.4.82-511655) but it is not going to be installed
 amdgpu-lib32 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:2.4.82-511655)
 glamor-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu but it is not going to be installed
 gst-omx-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 ids-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1:i386 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (= 1:2.4.82-511655) but it is not going to be installed
 libdrm-amdgpu-amdgpu1 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu (= 1:2.4.82-511655) but it is not going to be installed
 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa:i386 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libegl1-amdgpu-mesa : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libgbm1-amdgpu:i386 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libgbm1-amdgpu : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-dri : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-amdgpu-mesa-glx : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu but it is not going to be installed
 libglapi-amdgpu-mesa:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libglapi-amdgpu-mesa : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libllvm5.0-amdgpu:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libllvm5.0-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libwayland-amdgpu-client0 : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 : Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 libwayland-amdgpu-server0 : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 libxatracker2-amdgpu:i386 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libxatracker2-amdgpu : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu but it is not going to be installed
 mesa-amdgpu-omx-drivers : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu but it is not going to be installed
 mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers:i386 : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                                  Depends: amdgpu-core:i386
 mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers : Depends: libdrm2-amdgpu but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu : Depends: amdgpu-core but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And then, attempting to fix:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cinnamon-desktop-data gyp javascript-common libcinnamon-desktop4 libjs-inherits libjs-jquery libjs-node-uuid libjs-underscore libssl-dev libssl-doc
  libuv1 libuv1-dev linux-headers-4.10.0-28 linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-4.10.0-28-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic
  node-abbrev node-ansi node-ansi-color-table node-archy node-async node-block-stream node-combined-stream node-cookie-jar node-delayed-stream
  node-forever-agent node-form-data node-fstream node-fstream-ignore node-github-url-from-git node-glob node-graceful-fs node-gyp node-inherits
  node-ini node-json-stringify-safe node-lockfile node-lru-cache node-mime node-minimatch node-mkdirp node-mute-stream node-node-uuid node-nopt
  node-normalize-package-data node-npmlog node-once node-osenv node-qs node-read node-read-package-json node-request node-retry node-rimraf
  node-semver node-sha node-sigmund node-slide node-tar node-tunnel-agent node-underscore node-which zlib1g-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-dkms libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 libdrm2-amdgpu
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  amdgpu-dkms libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 libdrm2-amdgpu
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 56 not upgraded.
46 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,638 kB of archives.
After this operation, 127 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ amdgpu-dkms 17.50-511655 [5,578 kB]
Get:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm2-amdgpu 1:2.4.82-511655 [29.5 kB]
Get:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ libdrm2-amdgpu 1:2.4.82-511655 [30.5 kB]
(Reading database ... 334828 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amdgpu-dkms_17.50-511655_all.deb ...
Unpacking amdgpu-dkms (17.50-511655) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-dkms_17.50-511655_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-radeon.conf', which is also in package amdgpu-pro-dkms 17.40-492261
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libdrm2-amdgpu_2.4.82-511655_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm2-amdgpu:amd64 (1:2.4.82-511655) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./libdrm2-amdgpu_2.4.82-511655_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/udev/rules.d/91-amdgpu-pro-modeset.rules', which is also in package libdrm2-amdgpu-pro:i386 1:2.4.82-492261
Preparing to unpack .../libdrm2-amdgpu_2.4.82-511655_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm2-amdgpu:i386 (1:2.4.82-511655) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./libdrm2-amdgpu_2.4.82-511655_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/udev/rules.d/91-amdgpu-pro-modeset.rules', which is also in package libdrm2-amdgpu-pro:i386 1:2.4.82-492261
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-dkms_17.50-511655_all.deb
 /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./libdrm2-amdgpu_2.4.82-511655_amd64.deb
 /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./libdrm2-amdgpu_2.4.82-511655_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I would appreciate any ideas/guidance on how to fix this issue. At this point apt cant install or uninstall anything at all.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, as the solution there does not work always. What you could do is remove the packages with the `--force-all` switch, without that the purging/removing will likely not happen: `dpkg -P --force-all <package>`

Comment: same problem, this worked for me: `sudo rm -r /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/` -> `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu-pro.list` -> `sudo apt update` -> `sudo apt install synaptic` -> Mark all local installed amd packages for complete removal and apply. Reboot and install the new 17.50 driver.

Comment: I had delete `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/amdgpu-pro-local.list` in addition to what @kuhnroyal mentioned. After that, all worked fine, thank you!

Comment: Just in case, this is a single line list of packages to be installed when you install for `--pro` and `--opencl=legacy,pal` against `amdgpu-pro-install` script https://gist.github.com/haxpor/9aeb4cfca410a80cc10c9f00ef3c773d. Thus if something wrong, just use nerdoc 's suggestion to remove all packages in one line of command. I faced this and able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Same exact scenario for me. Tried a lot of things then something finally worked. At boot I selected advanced options:
Repair packages, it did a few things even got stuck and I hit ctrl+c then it continued with errors, after that it needed a ctrl +alt+del and it restarted.

sudo apt-get install update and sudo apt-get distro-upgrade showed that amd drivers will be removed. 
It removed it and I rebooted but could not log in (bounced back to login screen) Maybe here u can just do sudo chown username:username .Xauthority to fix it but I did not know about that yet so I I did a few other commands before doing the chown command (which fixed my login issue and all is well)
so after the distro-upgrade command i did
sudo apt-get purge amd*
installed 16.40 amd driver again
reboot

I am not sure why it worked, but maybe this helps you too.
Good luck

Comment: `recorvery mode -> repair packages -> reboot -> apt purge amd*` - worked for me

Comment: Might be "sudo-apt update" and "sudo apt dist-upgrade" now for you.